# Make undertow/wildFly support non-English content

Tags: encoding, jboss, wildfly, non-english, undertow

I am using WildFly9, but it seems support English encoding only!
Browser content of Chinese characters: '我们', changes to '￦ﾈﾑ￤ﾻﾬ' in server side!

I am looking for configuration help or even an undertow patch !
Can anyone help?Great thanks!

Comment: I am really worrying about this! Someone solves it, tell me your papal!

Answer (score 1):

You should set Undertow default encoding to UTF-8 (or maybe just your deployment).
Using the jboss-cli this should do the trick for the whole server:

> /subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribute(name=default-encoding,value=UTF-8)

Comment: What is the default encoding of your OS ?

Comment: bogon:~ happyyangyuan$ locale
LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
bogon:~ happyyangyuan$